# Regex-rule for matching single word during input (TipTap InputRule)

Tags: javascript, regex, tiptap, prose-mirror

I'm currently experimenting with TipTap, an editor framework.
My goal is to build a Custom Node extension for TipTap that wraps a single word in `<w>`-Tags, whenever a user is typing text. In TipTap I can write an [InputRule with Regex for this purpose](https://tiptap.dev/guide/custom-extensions#input-rules)

For example the rule `/(?:^|\s)((?:~)((?:[^~]+))(?:~))$/` will match text between two tildes (~text~) and wrap it with `<strike>`-Tags.

[Click here for my Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tiptap-input-rule-example-7hmnnr?file=/src/extensions/ext-wordnode.js)

I was trying for so long and can't figure it out. Here are the rules that I tried:

```
/**
 * Regex that matches a word node during input
 */

// Will match words between two tilde characters; I'm using this expression from the documentation as my starting point. 
//const inputRegex =  /(?:^|\s)((?:~)((?:[^~]+))(?:~))$/

// Will match a word but will append the following text to that word without the space inbetween
//const inputRegex =  /\b\w+\b\s$/

// Will match a word but will append the following text to previous word without the space inbetween; Will work with double spaces
//const inputRegex =  /(?:^|\s\b)(?:[^\s])(\w+\b)(?:\s)$/

// Will match a word but will swallow every second character
//const inputRegex =  /\b([^\s]+)\b$/g

// Will match every second word
//const inputRegex =  /\b([^\s]+)\b\s(?:\s)$/

// Will match every word but swallow spaces; Will work if I insert double spaces
const inputRegex =  /\b([^\s]+)(?:\b)\s$/
```

Comment: In the meantime I experimented with extending an already existing extension (CustomItalic).
The regex rule here is ```const inputRegex = /(?:^|\s)((?:\b)((?:[^\b]+))(?:\b))$/```

However, I need to press two spaces after every word for this to work.

Here is a 
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-wildflower-7hmnnr?file=/src/extensions/ext-custom-italic.js)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the choice of delimiter, which is space.

This becomes clear when we see the code for [markInputRule.ts](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/packages/core/src/inputRules/markInputRule.ts#L37) (line 37 to be precise)

```
    if (captureGroup) {
        const startSpaces = fullMatch.search(/\S/)
        const textStart = range.from + fullMatch.indexOf(captureGroup)
        const textEnd = textStart + captureGroup.length

        const excludedMarks = getMarksBetween(range.from, range.to, state.doc)
```

When we are using '~' as delimiters, the input rule tries to place the markers for start and end, without the delimiters and provide the enclosed-text to the extension tag (`CustomItalic`, in your case). You can clearly test this when entering strike-through text with enclosing '~', in which case the '~' are extracted out and the text is put inside the strike-through tag.

This is exactly the cause of your double-space problem, when you are getting the match of a word with space, the spaces are replaced and then the text is entered into the tag.

I have tried to work around this using negative look-ahead patterns, but the problem remains in the code of the file mentioned above.

What I would suggest here is to copy the code in [markInputRule.ts](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/main/packages/core/src/inputRules/markInputRule.ts#L37) and make a custom InputRule as per your requirements, which would be way easier than working with the in-built one. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying what you suggested, however the code in that file (markInputRule.ts) is triggered only after the regex-extraction and therefore after hitting double space. In this case I need to dig a bit deeper and currently I'm experimenting further with copies of tiptap code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem lies within the "space". Depending on the browser, the final "space" is either not represented at all in the underlying html (Firefox) or replaced with `&nbsp;` (e.g. Chrome).
I suggest you replace the `\s` with `(\s|\&nbsp;)` in your regex.